# NoClassDefFoundError when running Espresso tests on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-espresso, android-multidex, firebase-test-lab

I've got a suite of instrumentation tests that are meant to be run using the Firebase Test Lab on various physical devices from Android 4.4 through 8.

I can successfully run these tests locally on any OS version as well as on newer devices in the Firebase Test Lab, however when I run these tests in the Firebase Test Lab on devices running 4.4 (Currently running on a Moto X and a Galaxy S4 Mini), an exception is reported, even though the individual test cases all report success.  Here's the exception I'm seeing:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.junit.internal.TextListener FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner Process: today.onedrop.android.debug, PID: 5579 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.junit.internal.TextListener
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.listener.InstrumentationResultPrinter.instrumentationRunFinished(InstrumentationResultPrinter.java:221)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.reportRunEnded(TestExecutor.java:92)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:67)  
    at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:375)  
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1792)
```

I suspect that Firebase is actually not a factor and that these tests would fail in the same way if I had a Moto X or a Galaxy S4 Mini to test on locally.  Unfortunately I can't test that theory.

After updating my Espresso tests to use `TestOrchestrator`, I began getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` on Android 4.4 local AVD's as well. It's not the same one as above though:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Process: today.onedrop.android.debug, PID: 15683
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.junit.runner.Request
    at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:353)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

Using `TestOrchestrator` on Firebase produces the new error instead of the old one as well.  It's anyone's guess as to whether they share the same root cause, but their similarities definitely seem suspicious.

**UPDATE #2**

@MartinZeitler's instincts about MultiDex appear to have been right.  I've resolved <s>the second `NoClassDefFoundError`</s> both issues by adding the missing classes to a [multidex keep file](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#keep) in my gradle config:

```
multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
```

multidex-config.txt:

```
org/junit/runner/Request.class
org/junit/internal/TextListener.class
```

It would seem that multidex on 4.4 needs some help.  Or maybe this is just a hack that will just lead to random crashes with other missing classes. 
In any case everything is working again!

Comment: It will be easier for the Test Lab team to diagnose what's going on if you join the Firebase Slack in the #test-lab channel and ask there.  If you're not able to do that, please provide a link to your Firebase console to the test results where you see the error.

Comment: probably should be tagged `android-multidex` (while only five tags are permitted).

Comment: done, and for the record the multidex keep file fixed both issues

Comment: @Nick, It's helpful to make your solution an officially accepted answer in SO so we can upvote it. (and removes the green checkbox from the incorrect solution.) And thanks, the multidex keep file fixed it for me as well, though I'm using the proguard variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you add a dependency to jUnit? even on elder versions of Android, that library class should be known... leading to the assumption that you might also need to set `multiDexEnabled true` in the `build.gradle`, when building for Android < API 22 (which is enabled by default on all later API).

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

`gcloud firebase test android models list` lists devices...

```
┌───────────────────┬──────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┬──────────┬─────────────┬────────────────┬────────────┐
│      MODEL_ID     │   MAKE   │              MODEL_NAME             │   FORM   │  RESOLUTION │ OS_VERSION_IDS │    TAGS    │
├───────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼────────────────┼────────────┤
│ serranolte        │ Samsung  │ Galaxy S4 mini                      │ PHYSICAL │  960 x 540  │ 19             │            │
│ victara           │ Motorola │ Moto X                              │ PHYSICAL │ 1920 x 1080 │ 19             │            │
└───────────────────┴──────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┴──────────┴─────────────┴────────────────┴────────────┘
```

`gcloud firebase test android models describe serranolte`

```
brand: Samsung
codename: serranolte
form: PHYSICAL
supportedVersionIds:
- '19'
```

`gcloud firebase test android models describe victara`

```
brand: Motorola
codename: victara
form: PHYSICAL
supportedVersionIds:
- '19'
```

it's both hardware devices.

Comment: In my case it would be `androidTestImplementation` instead of `testImplementation` but yeah I did try that with no effect. I also already have multiDexEnabled set to true :(

Comment: @Nick not necessarily, opposite to the other rather Android specific testing libraries... maybe try getting a hardware device - or try an elder version of jUnit?

Comment: this still makes no sense on elder versions, because the classes should be contained - unless being over the 64k limit without multi-dex.

Comment: For the record, it was always a `testImplementation` dependency in this project, but those tests are pure unit tests that aren't instrumented and don't run on an Android device.  As far as an older version of JUnit, I'll give it a shot, but given that `TextListener` has been around for 10+ years I'm not hopeful.

Comment: Something that makes me think its not a multiDex issue is that these tests work just fine on an AVD running Android 4.4.  It's just older physical devices that fail, leading me to assume its some kind of issue with a manufacturer-butchered version of the OS on those devices.